# Selenium Distribute Load Accross Multiple Machines

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, webdriver-io

I've been reading about Selenium Grid, and I'm aware that I can create a Hub node and plug-in Nodes on this Hub/Master node.

But my question is: How does Selenium decide when to send the processing to a remote node?

And when it does send the processing to a remote node, if in my NodeJS script I'm working with files, in which file system will my script save the files?

Imagine a very simple script like:

```
client
  .init()
  .url('something')
  .getTitle()
  .then(function(title){ 
      /*save title to disk*/  
  });
```

This is a theoretical question, so for a correct answer I would expect references to documentation that can explain me the process. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the PDF referenced below:

> For running Selenium WebDriver tests in parallel, we need to set up
>   the Selenium Grid Server as a hub. This hub will provide the available
>   configurations or capabilities to the Selenium WebDriver tests. The
>   slave machines, also called as node, connect to hub for parallel
>   execution. Selenium WebDriver tests use the JSON wire protocol to talk
>   to the Hub |for executing Selenium commands. The Hub acts like the
>   central point, which will receive the entire test request and
>   distribute it to the right nodes.

You ask:

> How does Selenium decide when to send the processing to a remote node?

Not really sure about this, but I would expect it to give a random one from available nodes. If you want to, you can explicitly tell your code which node should run which test by using the `applicationName` `desiredCapability`, there is [a thread about it](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/PRsEBcbpNlM)

> And when it does send the processing to a remote node

When your test starts, a node is assigned to it and the processing (== test execution) starts..

> which file system will my script save the files

Whichever node is running the test will get the files.

For documentation, I would check [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2). I also find [this pdf](https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/downloads/Distributed_Testing_with_Selenium_Grid.pdf) easy to understand.